# How to use "SELECT * INTO ..." using laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to laravel and I cant seem to run this query in laravel.

```
SELECT * INTO tmp.dbo.dataset_15112022_124949 FROM tmp.dbo.dataset;
```

I have tried the following without any success

```
$archive_db = "SELECT * INTO tmp.dbo.dataset_15112022_124949 FROM tmp.dbo.dataset" ;
config(['database.connections.sqlsrv.database' => 'tmp']);
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->raw($archive_db);
```

Any help would be highly apreciated.

Comment: try to change `DB::connection('sqlsrv')->raw($archive_db)` to `$myResults = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(DB::raw($archive_db));` then: `dd($myResults);`

Comment: @ericmp this throws the following error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields. (SQL: SELECT * INTO tmp`

Comment: try `insert(` instead of `select(`, i misread and thought u wanted to select, but u actually want to do an insert, right?

Comment: `insert(` works 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code you will get a PDO instance:

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getPDO();
```

So you can execute a raw query with the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * INTO tmp.dbo.dataset_15112022_124949 FROM tmp.dbo.dataset;";
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getPDO()->query($sql);
```

Another approach is DB::statement($sql);

```
$sql = "SELECT * INTO tmp.dbo.dataset_15112022_124949 FROM tmp.dbo.dataset;";
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->statement($sql);
```